# injecting today's date in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When the page loads, I want a variable inside my JavaScript to hold today's date. So far I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TodayDate = <%Eval('System.DateTime.Now') %>;
</script>
```

It massively bugs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a javascript date object.

```
var today = new Date();
```

Or if you need the server time

```
var today = new Date('<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>');
```

Comment: Keep in mind the first option gives your client side date and the second option loads server side date and time. They could be different, especially if the client is in a different time zone.

Comment: Perfect! thanks. I'm interested in the date as a reference point and I handle time zones separately.

Answer (score 0):

is there anything in particular wrong with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TodayDate = new Date();
</script>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u use Javascript Date() object directly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TodayDate = Date();
</script>
```

Comment: Date is an object, hence you should add `new`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a variable containing the date on the *server*, your way of doing is probably good (except for the missing apostrophes and the Date constructor). So it should be:

```
var today = new Date('<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>'); 
//this assumes that the server has such a locale that DateTime.ToString can be
//parsed by the javascript interpreter
```

But, if you need to have the date of the *client*:

```
var today = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the previous people's answers of setting the date from within Javascript.

The problem you're seeing is that ASP is putting the string representing the current Date directly into the JavaScript source code. You need to put quotes around it so JavaScript sees a string and can parse it corretly.

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TodayDate = "<%Eval('System.DateTime.Now') %>";
</script>
```

which sets TodayDate to be a string. Are you going to use it as such or as a Date object?